# I am trying to run a website with fastcgi but i am having issues with the templates not rendering

Tags: python, django, nginx, fastcgi

Here goes:

I am running my website using fastcgi/nginx and django. I have managed starting the server, there are no errors. 
I ran manage.py runserver and visited the website, it has a menu which works under manage.py but when i start it using manage.py runfcgi:

```
python manage.py runfcgi method=prefork maxchildren=30 host=127.0.0.1 port=4300 pidfile=pid workdir="$PWD" daemonize=false outlog="$LOGFILE" errlog="$LOGFILE"
```

The application only serves me the first page in the website.

For example:

```
   If I go to mywebsite.com this being the home page I get the right 
   template home.html.
   If I visit mywebsite.com/get-started ,the server tries to render the same home.html.
```

Using manage.py runserver works, but with runfcgi it doesn't.

PS:
The website uses some cookies and it has a custom render function, it's the indextank service from github, the storefront app : https://github.com/linkedin/indextank-service
You can run it via manage.py.

Running it via runfcgi is not changing the page when I try to navigate the top menu, it makes the request but it gets on the same template which is 'home.html'

Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

An addition:
server fastcgi config which is pretty standard:

```
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

#fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;
```

and the application fastcgi config:

```
server {
        listen 80;
    server_name  search.spid.me www.search.spid.me;
        client_max_body_size 1m;

        location / {
            #fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:4300;
            include     fastcgi_params;
        #fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
            #fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
            #fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
            #fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;
        #fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO          $fastcgi_script_name;
        #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:4300;
            #fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
            #fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;
            #fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
            #fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME $server_name;
            #fastcgi_param SERVER_PORT $server_port;
            #fastcgi_param SERVER_PROTOCOL $server_protocol;
            #fastcgi_param CONTENT_TYPE $content_type;
            #fastcgi_param CONTENT_LENGTH $content_length;
            #fastcgi_pass_header Authorization;
            #fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
        }

        location /_static {
            expires 24h;
            autoindex on;
            alias /home/indextank/storefront/static/;
        }

        location /nginx_status {
            stub_status on;
            access_log off;
            deny all;
            allow 127.0.0.1;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
    }

 server {
    server_name  spid.search.me www.spid.search.me;
        listen 443;
        ssl on;
    #ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/conf.d/server.crt;
        #ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/conf.d/server.key;
        server_name  search.spid.me www.search.spid.me;
        client_max_body_size 1m;

        location / {
            fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:4300;
            include     fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
    }
```

I did some more debugging and it turns out that the path and path_info of the request are not getting set...

Comment: You haven't posted the important bit, which is your server FastCGI configuration.

Comment: just a thought ... could it be a problem of having DEBUG=True and/or a mismatch in where django expects to find your templates between debug mode and live mode?

Comment: Thought of that, i tried feeding it a very basic text rendering but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.
I was missing some fastcgi_params in the fastcgi params file.
I added those and it seems to have fixed the problem.

Comment: I had the same problem, was missing "fastcgi_split_path_info ^()(.*)$;" See https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DjangoAndNginx